# Javascript printing a variable

Tags: javascript, variables, printing, echo

I want to print a variable `auth` in the flashplayer.

For example:

```
var auth = x1c0de;

mplayer("content").setup({
  playlist: [{
    sources: [{
      file: 'http://dnswebsite.tld/appz?UserSign="I WANT MY auth VAR HERE"/playpath',
    }]
  }],
});
```

Comment: Is `x1c0de` supposed to be a string? Search for "string concatenation".

Answer (score 1):

```
file: 'http://dnswebsite.tld/appz?UserSign="' + auth + '"/playpath'
```

Is this what you're looking for ?

I'm confused by the simplicity of this... I must have missed something.

**EDIT:**

This is the snippet you gave me in your comment:

```
$.ajax({
    url: your_url,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (res) {
        var text = res.responseText;
        var auth = text.match("BEGIN(.*)/END");
    }
});
mplayer("content").setup({playlist: [{sources: [{file: 'http://dnswebsite.tld/appz?UserSign="I WANT MY auth VAR HERE"/playpath'}]}]});
```

Your problem is that your variable `auth` is stucked inside the scope of your success callback function. This should solve the problem:

```
var auth;
$.ajax({
    url: your_url,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (res) {
        var text = res.responseText;
        auth = text.match("BEGIN(.*)/END");
    }
});
mplayer("content").setup({playlist: [{sources: [{file: 'http://dnswebsite.tld/appz?UserSign="' + auth + '"/playpath'}]}]});
```

Comment: Hi thnx for replying to me i tried your code doesnt work here's the full code

//Getting the generated Auth Key
$.ajax({
    url: your_url,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(res) {
        var text = res.responseText;
  var auth = text.match("BEGIN(.*)/END");




    }

});


//this code will be ouputed for the user as html to play the media with JWplayer

mplayer("content").setup({
  playlist: [{
    sources: [{
      file: 'http://dnswebsite.tld/appz?UserSign="I WANT MY auth VAR HERE"/playpath',
    }]
  }],
});

Comment: yeah now i uderstand you passed the variable to global i test it with alert to print the variable but it shows undefined...when is out of $.ajax function...
so check the whole script in pastbin http://pastebin.com/vThxfXag
thnx for helping me